# Distribute items from a list into a new list

Tags: python, list, random

I have some lists:

```
original = [1234, 2456, 1245, 5734, 1245, 74512, 13678, 1456, 3926, 1974]
list1 = []
list2 = []
list3 = []
list4 = []
```

I'm trying to move a certain amount of numbers from the original list into the new lists. `list1` should have 4, `list2` should have 3, `list3` should 2, and `list4` should have 1. The numbers that go into the new lists should be picked randomly and not in any particular order. There also shouldn't be any of the same numbers in 2 lists; all lists should have unique numbers.
How should I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way, using `random.randrange` and `list.pop` (you said you want to "move" items from `original` so I assume it's supposed to be empty when you're done -- if not you could do this with a copy):

```
>>> import random
>>> original = [1234, 2456, 1245, 5734, 1245, 74512, 13678, 1456, 3926, 1974]
>>> list1 = []
>>> list2 = []
>>> list3 = []
>>> list4 = []
>>> for i, target in enumerate([list4, list3, list2, list1]):
...     for _ in range(i+1):
...         target.append(original.pop(random.randrange(len(original))))
...
>>> [list1, list2, list3, list4]
[[3926, 1234, 1456, 74512], [13678, 2456, 1245], [5734, 1245], [1974]]
>>> original
[]
```

Note that any time you have a bunch of numbered variables (like `list1`, `list2`, etc) it's usually easier to just make them a list:

```
>>> original = [1234, 2456, 1245, 5734, 1245, 74512, 13678, 1456, 3926, 1974]
>>> sublists = [[] for _ in range(4)]
>>> for i, s in enumerate(reversed(sublists)):
...     for _ in range(i+1):
...         s.append(original.pop(random.randrange(len(original))))
...
>>> sublists
[[1456, 1245, 5734, 1245], [13678, 74512, 2456], [1974, 3926], [1234]]
```

and once you've made your output a list of lists, you could build the whole thing as a comprehension if you wanted to:

```
>>> original = [1234, 2456, 1245, 5734, 1245, 74512, 13678, 1456, 3926, 1974]
>>> [[original.pop(random.randrange(len(original))) for _ in range(i)] for i in range(4, 0, -1)]
[[1234, 74512, 1974, 1456], [13678, 1245, 3926], [2456, 1245], [5734]]
```

Another option is to shuffle the list just once so you can simply pop the last element instead of selecting a random element each time:

```
>>> original = [1234, 2456, 1245, 5734, 1245, 74512, 13678, 1456, 3926, 1974]
>>> random.shuffle(original)
>>> [[original.pop() for _ in range(i)] for i in range(4, 0, -1)]
[[2456, 1245, 3926, 1974], [13678, 74512, 1234], [1245, 1456], [5734]]
```